# fixed point iteration algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numerical-analysis, fixed-point-iteration

I am asked to write a program to solve this equation ( x^3 + x -1 = 0 ) using fixed point iteration.

What is the algorithm for fixed point iteration? 
Is there any fixed point iteration code sample in Python? (not a function from any modules, but the code with algorithms)

Thank You

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Read this for start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29 While it's hard to understand, it's quite simple to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read this:
[Fixed point iteration:Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_iteration#Applications)

I chose Newton's Method.

Now if you'd like to learn about generator functions, you could define a generator function, and instance a generator object as follows

```
def newtons_method(n):
    n = float(n)  #Force float arithmetic
    nPlusOne = n - (pow(n,3) + n - 1)/(3*pow(n,2) +1)
    while 1:
        yield nPlusOne
        n = nPlusOne
        nPlusOne = n - (pow(n,3) + n - 1)/(3*pow(n,2) +1)

approxAnswer = newtons_method(1.0)   #1.0 can be any initial guess...
```

Then you can gain successively better approximations by calling:

```
approxAnswer.next()
```

see: [PEP 255](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) or [Classes (Generators) - Python v2.7](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators) for more info on Generators

For example

```
approx1 = approxAnswer.next()
approx2 = approxAnswer.next()
```

Or better yet use a loop!

As for deciding when your approximation is good enough... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode is [here](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/Web/FixPointIterationMod/Links/FixPointIterationMod_lnk_5.html), you should be able to figure it out from there.